# Check if string equals something then replace with img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to figure out the correct jQuery syntax to replace string with image **only if** it equals to specific string.

The div is pulling information from 'xml' so it can contain the following examples :

```
<div class="brand">Sony</div>
<div class="brand">Samsung</div>
<div class="brand">Sony Samsung</div>
```

So what I want is :

```
if ('.brand') == 'Sony' //replace text with img src="image1.jpg" <br/>
if ('.brand') == 'Samsung' //replace text with img src="image2.jpg" <br />
if ('.brand') == 'Sony Samsung' //then both images should show up in the div.**
```

I have been testing with the following line but wasn't able to get it to cover all cases.

```
.html('Sony', "<img src='image1.jpg' />");
```

Comment: You should provide some more information to your question..

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve that? I mean.. why not use data attributes, css or put the images straight in from the beginning?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m953v3aa/

Comment: i don't get ur problem...is with if? is with write the div with img tag? what?

Comment: @nevermind: What about case sensitivity?

Comment: That line you have been testing, `.html('Sony', "<img src='image1.jpg' />");`, makes no sense whatsoever. [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)  doesn’t even take two parameters ... Voting to close as too broad, because it seems you are only guessing.

Comment: @CBroe Voting to close because it seems that the OP is guessing would cover about 97% of all questions posted here. The question is not too broad. Please reopen - this is a valid question.

Comment: @CBroe I'm just trying to figure out the correct syntax and the best way to cover all cases.

Comment: @nevermind case sensitivity doesn't really matter, since it's pulling data from xml I know that the possible values will only be the ones I listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer that solves your stated problem:

```js
var brands = document.querySelectorAll(".brand");

brands.forEach(function(b){
  switch(b.textContent.toLowerCase()){
    case "sony":
      b.innerHTML = "<img src='image1.jpg' alt='image1.jpg' />";
      break;
    case "samsung":
      b.innerHTML = "<img src='image2.jpg' alt='image2.jpg' />";
      break;
    case "sony samsung":
      b.innerHTML = "<img src='image1.jpg' alt='image1.jpg' /><img src='image2.jpg' alt='image2.jpg' />";
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="brand">Sony</div>
<div class="brand">Samsung</div>
<div class="brand">Sony Samsung</div>
```

But, your stated use case is very brittle and the above solution would break down the moment your needs change. This version goes a step further and checks to see if Sony, Samsung or both are anywhere within the tag, so it doesn't have to be an exact match:

```js
var brands = document.querySelectorAll(".brand");

brands.forEach(function(b){
  
  var val = b.textContent.toLowerCase();
  if(val.indexOf("sony") > -1 && val.indexOf("samsung") > -1){
    b.innerHTML = "<img src='image1.jpg' alt='image1.jpg' /><img src='image2.jpg' alt='image2.jpg' />";
  } else if(val.indexOf("sony") > -1){
    b.innerHTML = "<img src='image1.jpg' alt='image1.jpg' />";
  } else if(val.indexOf("samsung") > -1){
    b.innerHTML = "<img src='image2.jpg' alt='image2.jpg' />";
  }
 
});
```

```html
<div class="brand">my favorite brand is Sony</div>
<div class="brand">Samsung is the best</div>
<div class="brand">Sony rules but Samsung is better</div>
```

Comment: If a man adds case sensivity he even gets my upvote.

Comment: There you go.. man jquery really teaches people how to pollute syntax and redundant calls :s

Comment: No kidding. They forget that the "J" stands for JavaScript!

Comment: **flawless**!!!

Answer (score 3):

There is an overload of [`jQuery.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) which takes a function, you can make good use of it here:

```js
$('.brand').html(function(i,text){
  var s = "";
  if(text.indexOf("Sony") > -1)
    s += "<img src=\"https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=Sony&w=150&h=50\">";
  if(text.indexOf("Samsung") > -1)
    s += "<img src=\"https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=Samsung&w=150&h=50\">";
  return s;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brand">Sony</div>
<div class="brand">Samsung</div>
<div class="brand">Sony Samsung</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Not sure to understand how the code covered the case with both images in the div. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

I think i don't get u, but is somthing like this that u want?

```js
if($('.foo').text() == 'sony') $('.foo2').html('<img/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var src1="http://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Sony-Logos.jpg";
var src2="http://www.brycomm.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Samsung-Logo.png";

$(".brand").each(function(i,a){
if($(a).text()=="Sony"){
$(a).html("<img class='resize'src="+src1+">");
}
  else if($(a).text()=="Samsung"){
$(a).html("<img class='resize'src="+src2+">");
}
  else if($(a).text()){
  $(a).html("<img class='resize'src="+src1+">"+"<img class='resize'src="+src2+">");
  }
})
```

```css
.resize {
    width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brand">Sony</div>
<div class="brand">Samsung</div>
<div class="brand">Sony Samsung</div>
```

Comment: Even if this works for this specific case the ending else is speculation and some case sensitivity should be added. (Wasnt me to downvote)

Comment: @downvoters do comment.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object called `brands` contain the informations you want to replace :

```
var brands = {'Sony':'<img src="image1.jpg"/>','Samsung':'<img src="image2.jpg"/>','Sony Samsung':'<img src="image1.jpg"/><img src="image2.jpg"/>'};
```

Then loop through all the brands `.brand` and replace assuming to the param you get from text :

```
$('.brand').each(function(){
    $(this).html(brands[$(this).text()]);
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var brands = {'Sony':'<img src="image1.jpg"/>','Samsung':'<img src="image2.jpg"/>','Sony Samsung':'<img src="image1.jpg"/><img src="image2.jpg"/>'};

$('.brand').each(function(){
  $(this).html(brands[$(this).text()]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brand">Sony</div>
<div class="brand">Samsung</div>
<div class="brand">Sony Samsung</div>
```

Comment: What if it is a case-insensitive match? What if there is more content in the tag besides the brand names?

Comment: The question was _only if it **equals to** specific string._ (not contains)

Comment: I know, but there are solutions that will cover both use cases and therefore be better answers.

Comment: If you're including the contains solution, so that may not what the OP want, when the question is **equals to** may the author meant i don't want the contains... e.g when the text is 'Sony xperia' it may that he don't want to replace..

Comment: True, I'm just saying that a better answer would address those possibilities.

Comment: YEES, it may ;)

Answer (score 0):

here it's a generic solution that should work for your case:

It works with all the images that you want and doesn't matter if you use capital letters or not. just add the new brand image to the brandImages object.

```js
var brandImages = {
 "sony" : 'http://flash.sonypictures.com/shared/global/images/sonypictures_share_200x200.jpg',
 "samsung" : 'http://www.samsung.com/us/images/common/samsung_logo_seo.jpg'
}

$('.brand').each(function() {
 var $this = $(this);
 var elems = $this.html().split(' '); //obtain the different brands
 $this.html(''); //clean the html wrapper
 $.each(elems, function (index, value) {
  $this.append('<img src="'+brandImages[value.toLowerCase()]+'" />') //append each image each image
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brand">Sony</div>
<div class="brand">Samsung</div>
<div class="brand">Sony Samsung</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something will help :

```
$('.brand').each(function() {
  if ($(this).html() === 'Sony') {
    $(this).html('<img src="test" />')
  }
});
```

Demo :

```
https://jsfiddle.net/mssecwL2/3/
```

But can't you do it without JS ? Just replacing the text with img at the beginning

Comment: That covers one third of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try it...Make the text in div and the name of image for this div same(like this Sony.jpg,Samsung.jpg,Sony_samsung.jpg)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var text=$(".brand").text();
  $(".brand").html('<img src='+text+'.jpg'/>
</script>
```